# React-Native map data and save all items

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have this code:

```
  this.state.viaturas.map((item, index) =>
    this.setState({preco: item.Preco, codigo: item.CodViatura})
  )
```

"preco" is only saving 1 item, when viaturas.map has more than 1 object, and more than 1 `item.Preco`.
And I want to save all `item.Preco` of all objects in an array or something.

Sorry for the bad explanation, but I've been dealing with bugs all day and I'm really tired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So all this is doing is looping over viaturas and overwriting preco with the next item in the loop. If I'm understanding correctly you want preco to be an array of all the preco's from viaturas and same with codigo so you can do something like this:

```
const preco = this.state.viaturas.map(item => item.Preco);
const codigo = this.state.viaturas.map(item => item.Codviatura);
this.setState({ preco, codigo });
```

Comment: it worked, thank you! Just a little edit: `this.setState({preco: preco, codigo: codigo})`

Comment: when a key and a value are the same word you can just do `{ preco, codigo }` and it'll work

Comment: After using the code I realised I needed something different, I need the `item.Preco` to be in the same array as `item.CodViatura` for each element. Like `[[ Preco: 9000, CodViatura: 45678], [Preco: 10000, CodViatura: 23456]]`

Comment: I got what I wanted with this code:           `const newItem = []
          this.state.viaturas.map((item, index) =>
            newItem.push([item.Preco, item.CodViatura]),
            this.setState({ stateArray: newItem })
          )`

Comment: ah ok cool, map returns an array so using that and pushing into an array is redundant, you can just do `const stateArray = this.state.viaturas.map(item => ([ item.Preco, item.CodViatura]);` and `this.setState({ stateArray });`

Answer (score 0):

You need concat these values to your state on one Array.

ejem:

```
this.state.viaturas.map((item, index) =>
    let newItem = {preco: item.Preco, codigo: item.CodViatura}
    this.setState({ stateArray: this.state.stateArray.concat(newItem) }) // Initial state to "stateArray: []"
  )
```

Comment: I get `unexpected token` on `let newItem` line.

Comment: I used something similar to your code to get what I wanted. For further reference, I used this:           `const newItem = []
          this.state.viaturas.map((item, index) =>
            newItem.push([item.Preco, item.CodViatura]),
            this.setState({ stateArray: newItem })
          )`